# TCP client in Firefox OS. No response from the server

Tags: tcpclient, firefox-os

I'm developing an app for Firefox OS which should communicate with the server via TCP connection. You can see the code below (the only difference is that I substituted actual ip address and port with variable names and excluded the content of `loginButes` (actually, there is exactly 24 bytes there)). The problem is that I can see only `"Sent successfully"` in console. So I don't obtain any response from the server at all. As far as I understand, there might be two possible reasons of this issue: either the data, I'm using in order to connect, is incorrect or the way, I'm trying to receive the response from the server, is wrong. Let's suppose that everything is fine with the data. Should my code receive a response or not? (i.e. should `socket.ondata` be executed if server sends me smth in response)

```js
(function() {
    var options = {binaryType='arraybuffer'};    
    var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(ip, port, options);

    sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var loginButes = [];
        var Int8View = new Uint8Array(loginBytes);

        socket.ondata = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            console.log("Received successfully");
        }
        socket.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("Everything is bad");
        }

        socket.send(Int8View);
        console.log("Sent successfully");
    });
})();
```

**P.S.** Thanks to the @DavidHoldeman's answer, I got rid of the initial issue and came to another one. I get `"uncaught exception: out of memory"` when sending the data now. Could you please suggest what might be the reason of that error?

Comment: Not sure but you're creating an array named `loginButes` and initializing an Uint8Array with a variable named `loginBytes` which isn't defined anywhere. Also check the size of the Int8View. If it's really 24 bytes, the length should be 24.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Could you please be more specific concerning `loginBytes`? Why do you say that it isn't defined anywhere if it is already declared and initialized array?

Btw, I printed the size of the `Int8View`. It is 24, as expected.

Comment: I already told you that you have a typo.. at line 6. You wrote `Butes`  not `Bytes`...

Comment: adding "use strict" to your function could help too.

Answer (score 0):

The 'options' argument passed to mozTCPSocket.open should be an object:

```
var options = { binaryType: 'arraybuffer' };
var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(ip, port, options);
```

This tripped me up the first time too. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! At least, your answer helped to get things moving!

Comment: Btw, sorry that I can't vote for your answer since I haven't enough reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the initial problem was replaced by another one. Could you please look into it? (see the update of my question)

Comment: See my answer to your other question.