# "Uncaught exception: out of memory" in TCP Client for Firefox OS

Tags: tcpclient, firefox-os

I'm trying to send some data over TCP connection from my TCP client for Firefox OS. Initially I started with filling `loginBytes` with the data which should help me to login to the service specified by `ip` and `port` (array's size is 28 bytes), now I'm trying to send an empty array. In any case the outcome is the same: in console log of Firefox Web IDE I can see the following message: `uncaught exception: out of memory`. And among the messages I tried to use for debugging only `"Started sending data"` is printed. So I come to a conclusion that the failure takes place during the execution of the `send` command. But what can be wrong with it?

```js
(function() {
    var sendButton = document.querySelector('#send');
    var notes = document.querySelector('#notes');
    var options = {binaryType: 'arraybuffer'};
    var socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(ip, port, options);

    sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {                           
        var loginBytes = [];
        var Int8View = new Uint8Array(loginBytes);      
        socket.ondata = function(event) {
            console.log("Started receiving data");
            console.log(event.data);
            console.log("Received successfully");
        }
        socket.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("Everything is bad");
        }
        console.log("Started sending data");
        socket.send(Int8View);
        console.log("Sent successfully");                                   
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
var Int8View = new Uint8Array(loginBytes)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
var Int8View = new Uint8Array(loginBytes).buffer
```

Uint8Array by itself does not return an ArrayBuffer object.

Comment: It helped to avoid the exception but once again leads to no response from server (so the behaviour looks in the same way as I described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982752/tcp-client-in-firefox-os-no-response-from-the-server). Have you any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I found what caused my problem. I used version `2.2` of Firefox OS simulator but [here](https://gist.github.com/timgluz/a15303d8b8c207a9e00f) people say that I need version `> 2.2`. In Firefox Nightly Build there is version `2.6`. Just tried it and it worked!